# Filter Firebase Children By Value Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have the below hierarchy in my firebase realtime databse, I want to get all children with specific value of the "status" child. How can I do that? Thanks in advance

[Firebase Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGL06.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

First open database ;

```
FirestoreDbBuilder builder = new FirestoreDbBuilder();
    //I am reading configs from json
      using (var stream = new StreamReader(@"appsettings.json"))
           {
              var obj = JObject.Parse(stream.ReadToEnd());
              var test = obj.SelectToken("AuthTokenOptions");
              builder.JsonCredentials = test.ToString();
              builder.ProjectId = "projectId";
              firestoreDb = builder.Build();
            }
    
    collection = firestoreDb.Collection(_collectionName);
```

Then you need to Query with your status Column

```
Query _query = collection.WhereEqualTo("status", "reserved");
QuerySnapshot allQuerySnapshot = await _query .GetSnapshotAsync(token);

 List<TEntity> entities = new List<TEntity>();

            if (allQuerySnapshot.Count > 0)
                foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in allQuerySnapshot.Documents)
                {
                    entities.Add(documentSnapshot.ConvertTo<TEntity>());
                };

            return entities;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I'm using Realtime Database not Firestore.

Comment: you need to var buyRef = db.ref("buy")  then buyRef.orderByChild("status").equalTo("reserved"). I hope this helps